# Is it common practice to charge additionnal fees to customer for renewing his hosting plan?

Tags: web-hosting, customer-service

I've made a website 2 years ago. The hosting plan needs to be renewed and the customer acknowledged that.

Do people usually charge only the hosting/domain fees or do they get charge an additionnal fee to get a cut on that too?

Comment: If you are working for client and if you will do additional charge than hosting service then they will get it easily that you have charged additional and that will not be good impression. Because in renew we really no need to do anything , all things handle by hosting people. So better you do not take additional charge.

Comment: I've built the website itself and plugged it on a CMS 2 years ago. Almost has forgotten about it. Recently received a warning from the hosting company telling me the website hosting plan is due next month. I got in touch with the customer telling them it should be renewed soon. Edit: I see your point. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Its great that you have informed to custom , now if your customer do all process then its fine. And if you will do renew process on behalf of customer then you should not take any additional charge if customer is of long term ,still if you feel that renew process will take your some time also then you can take little bit additional fee from customer bases on hours you spend for renew.

Comment: I have posted answer with little update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you are renewing hosting/domain of your customer on behalf of them then also you do not charge additional fee. It is good indication or we can say a positive point of business.

Because If you do renew process then also it will not consume your valuable time , All things will be done by hosting company so you will just need to pay invoice. Still If you think that hosting/domain renewal will consume your more time then you can take little bit additional fee from customer based on hours you spend during/for renew process.

Also make sure that if you take additional fee then be clear with your customer also that how many hours you spend and how much you are taking additional so in future your relationship with customer stay perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's common practice to charge for your time for *any* work you do for your client. Especially if you are fronting the money for him (i.e. paying the hosting fee out of your own pocket and getting reimbursed by him later).

How you charge your client is between the two of you, and should be spelled out in your contract. If you are maintaining a site for someone, it is reasonable to be paid a yearly maintenance fee (that could cover these third-party expenses).

If you wish to let your client deal with all this himself, you should set up the hosting arrangements so the client gets these emails instead of you.